# Expressing diagonal matrix using elementary matrices as generators in $\operatorname{SL}(\mathcal O_K \oplus \mathfrak a)$

Tags: matrices, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, matrix-decomposition

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field, $\mathcal O_K$ its ring of integers and an $\mathfrak a \subset K$ a fractional ideal. I've read in van der Geer that the group
$$\operatorname{SL}(\mathcal O_K \oplus \mathfrak a) := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}_2(K) : a,d \in  \mathcal O_K, b \in \mathfrak a^{-1}, c \in \mathfrak a \right\}$$
is generated by matricies of the form
$$\pm \begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\quad \pm \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ c & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

So I tried to express
\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \varepsilon^{-1}\end{pmatrix}
for $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K^\times$ with those matrices and was successful with an approach I developed using four matrices. This approach relied on a condition on the number field and I was not sure if it's always satisfied so I wrote a program to check that. It turned out that in $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{146})$ my approach doesn't work (for all squarefree $d<146$ it works in $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$).

Can anyone find a decomposition for $\varepsilon = 145 + 12\sqrt{146}$ being the fundamental unit and $\mathfrak a$ being any ideal which is not principal (for example $\mathfrak a:=(5,1+\sqrt{146})$ which is a prime ideal over $5$). By the way, the class number of $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{146})$ is $2$.

If you have a general approach this would help me even more.

**Edit:** A few days after posting this question I could show that there is no way for $d \in \{ 146, 170, 194, 221, 226, 254, 290, 291, 323, 326, 365, 386, 399, 410, 434, 439, 442, 445, 485, 499, 506, 514, 530, 533, 574, 579, 582, 646, 674, 706, 723, 730, 731, 785, 786, 791, 799, 839, 842, 866, 870, 890, 898, 899, 901, 910, 914, 959, 962, 965, 970, 982, 986 \}$ to do it for all units with only four matrices. This is due to how $(\varepsilon \pm 1)$ decomposes into prime ideals (and to which ideal classes they belong). So if van der Geer is right we need here at least five matrices and I'm very curious to see how this works.

Comment: This should be hard, because there are Dedekind domains where it is not true. For example, take $A = \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. The element $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} x&y\\-y&x \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is not a product of elementary matrices with entries in $A$. So you need to use some specific facts about rings of integers in number fields here. (On the other hand, maybe getting the diagonal matrices is easier than getting the full group.)

Comment: To spell out for other users why 146 is interesting: You can't do this with 4 matrices. The upper left entry of $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\w&1 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right] \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&x\\0&1 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right] \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\y&1 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1&z\\0&1 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ is $1+xy$ so we would have $\epsilon-1 = xy$ for $x \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $y \in \mathfrak{a}^{-1}$.  If $\mathfrak{a}$ is nonprincipal, then any product $(xy)$ of this form must have at least 2 non-principal prime factors.

Comment: But I get that all the factors of $\epsilon-1$ are principal: Specifically, $(\epsilon-1) = (12+\sqrt{146})^3 \cdot (12-\sqrt{146})^2  \cdot (3)$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Actually, we have $(12-\sqrt{146})=(12+\sqrt{146})$ because 2 is ramified. Further, because we allow $-1$ in our generators, it would be okay to have a non-principal ideal in the prime decomposition of $\varepsilon+1$. But there as well only principal ideals occur: $(\varepsilon+1)=(12-\sqrt{146})^2(73+6\sqrt{146})$. So in order to get our job done we have to look for a presenation of our matrix with using at least 5 elementary matricies. Due to van der Geer this should be possible.

Comment: If only for completeness, could you please give the exact reference (van der Geer)? Thanks...

Comment: @peterag Sure, it is "Hilbert modular surfaces" page 82.

Comment: To save other people some work, van der Geer cites Vasserstein "The group SL2 over Dedekind rings of arithmetic type" (1972) and says to also see Serre "
Le problème des groupes de congruence pour SL2" (1970). Vasserstein originally wrote in Russian; his work was translated into English but I can't find either the Russian original or the English translation online. Serre wrote in French, and, if you have JSTOR, you can read his paper here https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970630 . I can read mathematical French slowly but can't skim it; hopefully someone else can read faster.

Comment: It looks like Serre discusses this group on pages 520-523, but I don't see where he proves the result you want. (Easy to believe I missed something, though!)

Comment: I have found a possible replacement for Vasserstein: "On the group SL2 over orders of arithmetic type" Liehl (2009) aims to correct errors in Vasserstein's proof. Reading it now. One thing that is irritating: Liehl starts with two ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$. If we were allowed to take fractional ideals, then the case $I_2 = I_1^{-1}$ would be what you want. Liehl isn't saying that his results are right for fractional ideals, but it isn't clear yet whether or not there is a reason for this. https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1981.323.153